# "Update Model From Database" does not work in .edmx Entities file. My Database is DB2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, db2

I am trying to reflect new changes or add a new table to my model in EDMX file using 'Update Model From Database.' Then i get this error message in Update Wizard saying "Error retrieving Database information. An Item with the same key has already been added."

I am using DB2 database and VS 2010.

Please let me know how i can add a new table or reflect the changes to my model with the changes made to the database. Right now i am deleting the entire model and recreating the new one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error. In my case with DB2 9.5 LUW the solution was to remove duplicate named stored procedures on the server. DB2 lets you have multiple stored procs with the same name but different definitions (ie different parameters). But apparently this isn't compatible with Entity Framework. Fortunately for me the duplicates were actually unused old versions.

An alternative is to edit your EDM file in XML editor mode.

Answer (score -1):

I have followed the solution provided by vikrantislav. And in addition to that, I made one more change. By default EF tool brings objects from all the exiting schemas. So make sure you don't have duplicate store procedures in any of those schemas or change the connection properties to filter out by a specific schema. In my case I have filtered out by specific schema as I don't want to mess up with someone else's store procedures in other schemas. And now "update model from database" wizard started working. what a relief.

[Schema filter in connection properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrEkP.jpg)

Comment: To the person who down voted, Could you please explain what was the issue you had where my answer/solution did not help resolve it?